# How to separate out the regression effect vs treatment effect without a control group?

Tags: regression, psychology, pre-post-comparison

I'm looking at a dataset that has pre-post test measurements on users' stress, depression and anxiety levels collected from a website's online health assessment. On average, the healthier participants at baseline got worse over time, and the sicker participants at baseline got much better, and the middle group gets a little better. There's definitely a regression effect going on here, but also a treatment effect too.

As this data was collected based on website usage, there isn't really a control group (all of the "post" measurements come from people that have used the online program). There are probably ways that I could synthesize a control group using the people who I can guess didn't make much use out of the treatment (based on number of logins or length of time between logins), but is there a way to separate out the treatment effect from the regression effect when you can't use difference-in-difference techniques using a control group or anything like that?

Comment: What's the treatment? (I don't see any mention of one).

Comment: You cannot distinguish the "online program" effect from any sort of time/placebo effect

Comment: Peter, sorry, should have been clearer. This site has coaching tools and online content to help people manage these mental health conditions, so the "treatment" is the use of these resources.